# Deploying with Maven Tomcat plugin failes

Tags: maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy application using tomcat7-maven-plugin with this configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/Ohta</path>
        <username>tomcat</username>
        <port>8080</port>
        <password>s3cret</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I get the folowing error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project ohta: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
```

As I understand maven tries to use org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin instead of specified and can't find configuration, but why it is so?

Comment: are you doing mvn tomcat7:run ?

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Now I'm trying to run application using tomcat7:run -  server starts, it seems that all is ok but when I open aplication url I get 404 eror...

Answer (score 2):

This link contains a good tutorial about [Maven Tomcat plugin](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.it/2014/04/tomcat-maven-plugin-tutorial.html). Might be useful to see the whole process from archetype creation to deployment using the plugin.